# Group gets height from original image, not the scaled image

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

In my app I import a twitter timeline. Some tweets contain images, some don't. Also the height of the imqages is variabel. I have a set width of 90% to make sure the images fit in the group (with a vertical layout), but no matter what I do, the group gets it's height from the original image, not the scaled height. I tried setting variableRowHeight="true", but that doesn't seem to do anything.Here is some sample code:

```
<s:List id="list" y="0" width="90%" height="954" dataProvider="{tweets}" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:Group width="100%">
                <s:Label id="twitlabel" text="{tweetImage.height}"
                             width="100%"
                             styleName="tweetlist"/>
                    <s:Image id="tweetImage" y="{twitlabel.height}" width="90%" horizontalCenter="0" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" source="{data.entities.media[0].media_url}"/>
                </s:Group>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
```

The question is, how can I get the group to set it's height to the scaled image height?

Comment: Try this: `<s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" useVirtualLayout="false" variableRowHeight="true" />`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that didn't work, still got this huge gaps in the items of the group. Also, when I set the Image class to BitmapImage, it works, but then sometimes the image is not displayed (but the group is as big as the image).

Answer (score 0):

First set the "complete" event handler for your Image and an id for your Group:

```
 <s:Group id="tweetImageGroup" width="100%">
 <s:Image id="tweetImage" y="{twitlabel.height}" horizontalCenter="0" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" source="{data.entities.media[0].media_url}" complete="tweetImage_completeHandler(event)"/>
```

Then set the width after the image has completed loading:

```
protected function tweetImage_completeHandler(event:Event):void{
   tweetImageGroup.height = event.currentTarget.measuredHeight;
}
```

This might need some adjusting but should work if I understood your problem correctly.